# Recommend XML Difference open source Java libraries?

Tags: java, xml

I have a requirement to compare two XML documents and report differences.  String comparison is not sufficient as I want to be able to say that:

```
<Foo/>
```

is the same as

```
<Foo></Foo>
```

Anyone used a library they would recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the cunningly named [xmldiff](https://xmldiff.dev.java.net/) which I've used before with success.

[XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) also works well. It's primarily for use in unit tests (alongside JUnit).

Comment: I must be not looking in the right places, but i can't find any files for xmldiff.

Comment: It's some time since I used it. I'm wondering if I did a direct CVS checkout

Comment: Going with XMLUnit, which I know vaguely

Answer (score 0):

or try [diffxml](http://diffxml.sourceforge.net/):

> The standard Unix tools diff and patch
>   are used to find the differences
>   between text files and to apply the
>   differences. These tools operate on a
>   line by line basis using well-studied
>   methods for computing the longest
>   common subsequence (LCS).
>
> Using these tools on hierarchically
>   structured data (XML etc) leads to
>   sub-optimal results, as they are
>   incapable of recognizing the
>   tree-based structure of these files.
>
> This project aims to provide Open
>   Source XML diff and patch utilities
>   which operate on the hierarchical
>   structure of XML documents.

Comment: The website says " The current version is 0.95 Beta. Please note that this is an beta release; it is not yet production quality."  Which makes it a bit difficult to justify in the corporate world.

Answer (score 0):

What I always do is format both sides of the XML (xmllint -format) and diff the results.

Comment: Which would flag `<FOO/>` as different fom `<FOO></FOO>`.